# Delta Robot: Torque and Motor Sizing

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, robotics

Question: Is 56 Nm enough torque for a delta robot with the below dimensions and specs? If not, what would be the minimum torque needed? Thank you in advance for your help.

I am working on a rotary delta arm design and needed help sizing the correct motor and gearbox. Below are the mechanical dimensions of the arm and application info.

Delta Arm Specs:

- Base Radius (Center to Motor): 200 mm
- Primary Arm Length: 279.4 mm
- Secondary Arm Length: 441.96 mm
- End Effector Radius: 100 mm
- The arms are carbon fiber: Weight of arms is approx: 445 grams
- The gripping mechanisms weight between 300 grams to 1 kg

Application Info:

1. Type: Pick and Place
2. Max Payload: 3 kg
3. Min picks per minute: 60
4. Max pick per minute: 100

I have been looking at using Teknic Clearpath motors with a planetary gearbox from Anaheim Automation.

- Teknic [NEMA 23 Motor](https://www.teknic.com/model-info/CPM-SCHP-2341S-ELNB/?model_voltage=75VDC) Peak Torque: 5.8 Nm | Const (RMS) Torque: 1.2 Nm | Max RPM: 1860 with a 10 to 1 single stage gearbox [Anaheim Automation Gearbox](https://www.anaheimautomation.com/products/gearbox/planetary-gearbox-item.php?sID=625&pt=i&tID=1089&cID=30) Arc-Min: 3.  At gear output expecting: Peak Torque: 56.26 Nm and Const Torque: 11.64 Nm. RPM Expected: 186

Here is a gif of the delta arm and its movement (Wikipedia) [Delta Arm Sketch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_robot#/media/File:DeltaRamki.gif)

Comment: What is the mass of the arms and gripping mechanism? You need this to work out the total mass to be mived and the inertial load acceleration etc

Comment: @SolarMike The mass of each set of arms is approx 148 grams and the gripper mechanisms weigh between 250 grams to 1 kg.

Comment: @vcesena3, fascinating, but too complicated. I don't think I can help you with that. I deleted my answer.